# Limitar retorno de registros devueltos

Tags: sql, informix, tora

Actualmente aplico una query para obtener x datos, y cuando importo a excel este resultado sobrepasa la capacidad de este.

Me gustaría que la query me entregue los últimos 3 registros por rut, para poder revisar las gestiones de cobranza de dichos clientes. Me ayudan con esto por favor? (':

Query:

```
select * 
  from cre_venta_cuotas 
  join cc_gestion_cob
    on cre_venta_cuotas.rut_cliente = cc_gestion_cob.rut_cliente
 where fecha_castigo between "01-01-2021" and "31-01-2021"
   and fecha_gest >= "01-01-2021"
```

Comment: Si mal no entiendo tu pregunta, lo que necesitas es seleccionar los primeros tres resultados que aparezcan en tu query, ¿no? Si es así, puedes utilizar el `SELECT TOP 3 * ...` y recuerda hacer el order by para que te lo muestre de forma descendiente

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu manejador de base de datos? Considera poner una etiqueta al respecto en la pregunta.

Comment: @xBeiker no, el `TOP 3` directo no va a funcionar, porque necesita los 3 últimos por cada rut. Felipe, cuál es la columna que contiene la fecha por la cual ordenar? (cómo sabemos cuáles son los "últimos" registros?)

Comment: A.Cedano  hola amigo, mi manejador de TOra3 (la página no me dejó poner etiqueta de esto).      
@Lamak la columna para ordenar sería fecha_gest y sabemos los últimos 3 registros porque son los 3 más actuales según la fecha.
Mis columnas principales serían: Rut, fecha_castigo, fecha_gest (que es la fecha de gestión de cobranza) y cod_gest (codigo de la gestión, por ej: Cod 1: Cliente copromete a pagar; Cod 2: cliente  no desea cancelar deuda, etc).

Comment: Felipe, con Tora te comunicas a una base de datos. No importa con que programa te comunicas, si no que base de datos usas. la query puede tener sutiles diferencias, y en otros casos grandes diferencias. por ejemplo, top 3 solo funciona en sql server. Asi que por favor, usa el boton [edit] y agrega que base de datos usas en las etiquetas...

Comment: @gbianchi es informix, muchas gracias amigo!

Comment: Utiliza la palabra FIRST, ejemplo:  SELECT FIRST 10 * FROM TABLA ORDER BY X

Comment: Eso solo me devuelve 3 registros, yo necesito 3 últimos registros por rut...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No especificas que version de Informix utilizas, si es la version 12.10 o 14.10 puedes utilizar la funcionalidad [Lateral derived tables](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=clause-lateral-derived-tables), es un subquery que puedes especificar en la parte FROM del SELECT y hacer un join con la tabla principal.

No especificas la estructura de las tablas por lo que el ejemplo que te pongo no lo he podido probar, suponiendo esta estructura basica:

```
cre_venta_cuotas: rut_cliente, fecha_castigo, ...
cc_gestion_cob: rut_cliente, fecha_gest, ...
```

El query quedaria de esta forma:

```
SELECT cre_venta_cuotas.*, t.*
  FROM cre_venta_cuotas,
       LATERAL (SELECT FIRST 3 cc_gestion_cob.*
                  FROM cc_gestion_cob
                 WHERE cc_gestion_cob.rut_cliente = cre_venta_cuotas.rut_cliente
                 ORDER BY cc_gestion_cob.fecha_gest DESC) AS t
 WHERE fecha_castigo BETWEEN "01-01-2021" AND "31-01-2021"
```